# Function overloads to accept all types of function

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program which accepts a function with any non-zero number of parameters and reduces it using std::bind to a function that takes only one parameter.

The latter part of the problem is fine, but I wish the user to be able to input any type of function - std::function, function pointer, functor or lambda - and I do not know how to write a template parameter that will accept the last two types and allow me to deduce the number of arguments the function takes.

Please find below sample code with a 'foo' function which is overloaded to accept function pointers and std::functions - if anyone could point me in the right direction as to how to write the other two overloads I would be very grateful.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Ret, typename ParamA, typename... Params>
unsigned int foo(const std::function<Ret(ParamA, Params...)>& f)
{
    return sizeof...(Params);
}

template <typename Ret, typename ParamA, typename... Params>
unsigned int foo(Ret(*f)(ParamA, Params...))
{
    return sizeof...(Params);
}

unsigned int foo(/*accepts a functor*/);

unsigned int foo(/*accepts a lambda*/);

std::function<void(int)> std_func([](int) {});
void f_ptr(int, int) {}
struct functor { void operator () (int, int, int) {} };
auto lambda = [](int, int, int, int) {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(std_func); //Passed in a std::function
    std::cout << foo(f_ptr); //Passed in a function pointer
    std::cout << foo(functor()); //Passed in a functor
    std::cout << foo(lambda); //Passed in a lambda

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not well-defined. A functor (a class with `operator()`) may provide multiple overloads of `operator()`, taking different number and types of parameters. Which of them is your function expected to act on?

Comment: You don't have to worry about it, since `std::bind` will bind parameters of any callable object. However, one thing you have not fully explained is what exactly do you want to bind each parameter to. You can't just bind a parameter to something unspecified. The whole purpose of `std::bind` is to assign a discrete value to the function parameter. So what exactly are you trying to bind?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik For example, I might want to accept functions which take integer parameters, and bind the position of the parameter to it, for example foo(int a, int b, int c) would become foo(int a, 1, 2)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, that's a good point I overlooked

Comment: Well, then, just use `std::bind` directly. As I said, `std::bind` will wrap any callable object. I don't see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
// Accepts a pointer to member function
template <typename T, typename Ret, typename ParamA, typename... Params>
unsigned int foo(Ret (T::*f)(ParamA, Params...))
{
    return sizeof...(Params);
}

// Accepts a pointer to const member function
template <typename T, typename Ret, typename ParamA, typename... Params>
unsigned int foo(Ret (T::*f)(ParamA, Params...) const)
{
    return sizeof...(Params);
}

// Accepts a function object, including lambda and std::function
template <typename F>
unsigned int foo(const F& func) {
    return foo(&F::operator());
}
```

Only works on a function object with one, non-overloaded `operator()`. Since `std::function` is also such an object, the dedicated overload for `std::function` is no longer necessary (but one for plain function pointer is still needed).

[Demo](http://rextester.com/WKT22008)